# Efficiently shrink data by getting rid of every other bit

Tags: c++, binary

My source data is redundant and every bit is duplicated. I'm rearranging and processing this data and there are several gigs of data. I mostly work in python but have switched to working with C++ because of processing speed limitations though I'm not familiar with all the nuances. 
If this is my raw data: `1100 0011 1100 1100` I want it to look like this: `1001 1010` My solution would be to bit compare each position and compose the new data bit by bit. Is there a more efficient method of doing this?

Apparently this confused people here is another attempt to illustrate the question.

INCOMING DATA: 1100 1100 0011 0011

DESIRED  DATA: 1x0x 1x0x 0x1x 0x1x

CORRECTED    : 1010 0101

The incoming data has every bit represented twice. There are two 1s and two 0s where there should be only one 1 and one 0. Rather than checking the state of the bit then shifting that into a new byte what is a more efficient solution?

Comment: This question is unclear. How is this data created and where is it from?

Comment: have  a look  at  the bit shift operator; take care to use some  `unsigned`  data type.

Comment: @xaav the source of the data is irrelevant. I have no control over its creation.

Comment: There are only 16 possible combinations per byte, so a mapping table should make pretty quick work of the problem.

Comment: @StephanLechner I would need to first get the state of the bit and then shift it into position. This is already the proposed solution in my original question. Unless you are telling me its possible to simply shift all bits without knowing its contents?

Comment: @user4581301 I'll look into this sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the idea of @user4581301, you could use a mapping table that maps each possible 16 bit input into the corresponding 8 bit "shrinked" target. Note, however, that this (sparse) mapping table needs 65536 entries, since this is the  range of your 16 bit input. Of course, this approach only makes sense if you have to transform lots of 16 bit input values (such that the time for preparing the mapping table does not count):

```
uint8_t map2uint8[65536];

void prepareMappingTable() {
    for (uint16_t i=0; i<=255; i++) {
        // dublicate the bits:
        uint16_t position = 0;
        uint16_t targetBit = 1;
        for(uint16_t sourceBit = 1; sourceBit<=128; sourceBit <<= 1) {
            if(i&sourceBit) {
                position |= targetBit;
                position |= (targetBit << 1);
            }
            targetBit <<= 2;
        }
        map2uint8[position] = i;
    }
}

int main(){

    prepareMappingTable();

    uint16_t input = 0b1100001111001100;
    uint8_t output =  map2uint8[input];

    cout <<  bitset<8>(output) <<  endl;
    return 0;
}
```